# Spring Boot containers can not connect to the Kafka container

Tags: docker, spring-boot, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I'm trying to use microservices `Spring Boot` with `Kafka`, but my `Spring Boot` containers can not connect to the `Kafka` container.

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:

  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 2181:2181

  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    container_name: kafka
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    links:
      - zookeeper:zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: localhost
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181

  consumer:
    image: consumer
    container_name: consumer
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8084:8080
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    links:
      - kafka:kafka

  producer:
    image: producer
    container_name: producer
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8085:8080
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    links:
      - kafka:kafka
```

`application.properties` in Consumer:

```
spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers=kafka:9092
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=WorkUnitApp
spring.kafka.consumer.topic=kafka_topic
```

`application.properties` in Producer:

```
spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers=kafka:9092
```

## But if I run the `Kafka` in a container and the `Spring Boot` microservices locally it works.

`application.properties` in Consumer:

```
spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers=0.0.0.0:9092
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=WorkUnitApp
spring.kafka.consumer.topic=kafka_topic
```

`application.properties` in Producer:

```
spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers=0.0.0.0:9092
```

What's the problem, why does the `links` from the `docker` not work ?

p.s. **0.0.0.0** because `mac os`

## Edited

I added in `docker-compose.yml` environments to `kafka` but it still does not work either

```
  - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT=9092
```

Comment: We were in the same situation, and I am not sure exactly how this works, but we were able to set up the container in a way that it could be connected to from both outside and inside using the multiple protocol setup described in the documention example (the INSIDE/OUTSIDE part): https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker#example

Comment: Are you on mac or Linux?

Comment: Have you tried setting `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME` to `kafka`?

Comment: @Thilo I looked but I did not succeed  (the INSIDE/OUTSIDE part)

Comment: @AlexKarshin mac os

Comment: @SzymonBiliński I added       - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=localhost
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT=9092, but it does not work

Comment: please try `localhost` instead of `kafka`: `spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092`.

Comment: I've meant the opposite - have you tried `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=kafka` ?

Comment: @SzymonBiliński thanks a lot it works,  KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=kafka

Comment: @alexuio Cool. I've posted an answer to reflect this for future reference.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to advertise your **Kafka** broker as `kafka`, which is the effective hostname for all linking containers (i.e. the hostname that the client needs to connect to from the **Kafka** protocol perspective, and so `kafka:9092` is correct, not `0.0.0.0`):

```
kafka:
  ...
  environment:
    KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka
```

Comment: what is the difference between "advertised host name" and "bootstrap servers" in kafka configuration? I cannot figure it out from documentation

Comment: @voipp "advertised host name" tells the node how it should present itself to the world (i.e. how other cluster members should connect to it). "bootstrap servers" defines a list of Kafka nodes, that should be used for the initial setup (i.e. to fetch the _actual_ list of cluster members).

Comment: thanks for help. From the perspective of kafka client (i.e. kafkaTool), what host it will connect to? host from advertised host or from bootstrap servers?(in case they are different). May be you have good article explaining such topics?

Comment: @voipp The client will connect to bootstrap servers to get a list of active nodes to connect to. Entries on that list will be advertised host names (+ advertised port) of each server. You should probably open a new question, if you have a concrete setup problem, as this is a bit out of scope of the initial issue (i.e. why can't the client connect to a Kafka server within Docker). Also, keep in mind that a given property is usually scoped to a specific [place](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/configuration/index.html).

Comment: To clarify, `bootstrap.servers` is a client property, not a broker/server property. My first comment might have been slightly misleading here. Servers use ZooKeeper for synchronizing internally.

Comment: why do we need to to have bootstrapServers on client? Why don't we provide host and port to clients so they can communicate to brokers without 'bootsttrapping', with only one request?

Comment: I have a spring-boot container that is on a custom network, and when I try connecting `bootstrap.servers=kafka:9092` it says that this url isn't defined. Could this simply be because I need my docker-compose to be running on my custom network?

Comment: @frlzjosh Containers need to be on the same network to find one another, as with any other two servers

Comment: Should be mentioned that the host name and port values are deprecated in favor of advertised listeners