# Getting "Broker may not be available" error when spring boot container tries to connect kafka container

Tags: spring-boot, docker, apache-kafka

I am running into a problem with spring boot kafka docker, tried all the things mentioned in the below link but the issues still remain.

[Spring Boot containers can not connect to the Kafka container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48245398/spring-boot-containers-can-not-connect-to-the-kafka-container)

Attaching my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
    - "2181:2181"
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    container_name: kafka
    ports:
    - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
  my-app:
    image: my-app
    container_name: my-app
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - kafka
```

The error log

```
-1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
my-app     | 2020-11-03 08:10:21.444  WARN 1 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
```

I am running wrustmiester/kafka and wrustmiester/zookeeper.
If I run locally the spring boot app, everything runs smoothly.
The issue comes when I try to build an image of my spring boot app and run that image. Then the error is Broker may not be available.
Please if anyone can guide me.

Adding my application.yml

```
spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
      group-id: group_id
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value-deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
      #org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      properties.spring.json.trusted.packages: com.myapp.pojo

    producer:
      bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      value-serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
      #org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
```

**Updated my docker-compose.yml as**

```
version: '3'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    network_mode: bridge
    ports:
    - "2181:2181"
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    container_name: kafka
    network_mode: bridge
    ports:
    - "9092:9092"
    hostname: kafka
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
     # KAFKA_LISTENERS: INSIDE://:9092,OUTSIDE://:9094
     # KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
     # KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INSIDE
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: 9092
    links:
      - zookeeper
  my-app:
    image: my-app
    container_name: my-app
    network_mode: bridge
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - kafka
```

**Updated my application.yml as**

```
spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      bootstrap-servers: kafka:9092
      group-id: group_id
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value-deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
      #org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      properties.spring.json.trusted.packages: com.myapp.pojo

    producer:
      bootstrap-servers: kafka:9092
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      value-serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
      #org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
```

**Error log is same**

```
WARN 1 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
my-app     | 2020-11-03 17:05:39.585  WARN 1 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
```

Comment: See https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-client-cannot-connect-to-broker-on-aws-on-docker-etc

Comment: Just providing a link won't help , please tell me where i have made error

Comment: As mentioned in the blog, connecting to localhost is incorrect. Within the app container, it refers to the app container, not the broker. Your producer and consumer cannot connect to anything within the app container

Answer (score 5):

I was able to resolve my issue.

Here is my updated docker-compose.yml that works and the rest of the configuration is the same as above

```
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1

  my-app:
    image: my-app
    container_name: my-app
    environment:
      SPRING_KAFKA_BOOTSTRAPSERVERS: kafka:29092
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    depends_on:
      - kafka
```

Changes made were

1. I have used confluent Kafka and zookeeper but even the above docker-compose.yml with wrustmeister Kafka and zookeeper would work.
2. Most important property

   **environment:
   SPRING_KAFKA_BOOTSTRAPSERVERS: kafka:29092**
3. Also as suggested by @OneCricketeer

> Alternatively, if all three clients are communicating with the same
> cluster, remove bootstrap servers from the producer and consumer, and
> set it globally with spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers

Even this should work I feel.
Maybe I can try this sometime later and will update my answer.

Comment: thnks it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Your error is coming from the AdminClient, so if you aren't manually creating an instance of that in your code, you need to add a config section for `spring.kafka.admin.*` with bootstrap-servers set there as well

Alternatively, if all three clients are communicating with the same cluster, remove bootstrap servers from the producer and consumer, and set it globally with `spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers`

Since you're using Docker networking, the address will need to be the Kafka container's hostname. Also note that `links` are a deprecated Compose feature and shouldn't be relied on

Comment: All the details that you mentioned would not help me solve the problem. Can you please share some code snippets and point out what wrong have I done in the configuration. Also, there are not 3 clients. I have 1 spring boot rest app communicating with Apache Kafka

Comment: "Your error is coming from the AdminClient, so if you aren't manually creating an instance of that in your code, you need to add a config section for spring.kafka.admin.* with bootstrap-servers set there as well" -> the same code works when I run spring boot app locally with Kafka and zookeeper images running on docker, So I don't think there is any issue in creating Admin instance. Please read my question and let me know if I have missed any other details.

Comment: I did read your question. You cannot compare "running locally" with running everything in Docker. Simple as that - if you tried to deploy your container anywhere else (the main point of using Docker), it also wouldn't work. The error clearly shows that `localhost` is still being used in the code somewhere, and without actually seeing your full spring app, hard to say where that would be because your config file is not showing that (unless the admin properties default to localhost, and you have no section mentioning it). If you are fine running everything locally, then don't use Docker

Comment: Running locally means Spring boot is running locally but Kafka and zookeeper in on docker. So basically my spring-boot app communicates with docker images. Also if you need any other details or config files I am ready to post it, Let me know. Also, i can share my GitHub link of project if required.

Comment: What I meant is that, commonly Kafka would be on a remote cluster environment. (For example, Amazon MSK). Your code would have the same error in that case. But yes, It would be necessary for your full stacktrace and your code for where the AdminClient is created/used

Answer (score 0):

can you try this once

```
version: '3'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
    - "2181:2181"
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    container_name: kafka
    ports:
    - "9092:9092"
    hostname: kafka
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
     # KAFKA_LISTENERS: INSIDE://:9092,OUTSIDE://:9094
     # KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
     # KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INSIDE
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: 9092
    links:
      - zookeeper
  my-app:
    image: my-app
    container_name: my-app
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - kafka
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: bridge
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed by configuring a KafkaAdmin bean in my Spring-Boot application and passing the bootstrap-servers property:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class CpoExecutorApplication {

    @Value("${spring.kafka.template.default-topic}")
    private String topicName;

    @Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapAddress;

    @Bean
    public KafkaAdmin kafkaAdmin() {
        Map<String, Object> configs = new HashMap<>();
        configs.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        return new KafkaAdmin(configs);
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic processTopic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name(topicName).partitions(2).build();
    }
....
```

application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8000
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: localhost:9094
    consumer:
      auto-offset-reset: false
    template:
      default-topic: process-topic
.....
```

This way I didn't need to pass the SPRING_KAFKA_BOOTSTRAPSERVERS environment variable in docker-compose.yml.

Answer (score -1):

I had done same thing in almost same way(small difference), just have a look at the below compose-file, if this works for you

```
version: '3'

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    hostname: kafka
    environment:
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=kafka
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT=9092
    links:
      - zookeeper
```

Comment: should I mention hostname in application.yml for bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092, instead of localhost -> kafka

Comment: No you need to access kafka with the service or container-name in this case kafka, so basically you should use kafka:9092 in your application.yml file

Comment: yes i have replaced localhost:9092 to kafka:9092. But issue still persist

Comment: @Ajinkya Then edit your question to reflect the changes and new error message

Comment: @OneCricketeer, I have updated the question and the error remains the same.